# My HTC Android Touch is creating problems some times

Tags: htc-desire

All of a sudden with out touching the screen my phone works on its own like moving between screens.  If I touch on one option it may navigate to some other. It happens very rarely, but it's impacting my ability to use the phone. Can any one suggest a solution?

Comment: Do you have an HTC Desire or HTC MyTouch? The tags say one thing but your title (seems) to say something else.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a digitizer problem, you should take it to a warranty. Usually problems like that can be cause of a digitizer issue.

Comment: this started to happen after i downloaded an app from the market. prior to that it was great. but after downloading that app all the heck started. anyways I have uninstalled that app but i did not get rid of the problem completely as it was peeping in sometime or the other.. but rare..

Comment: @yrksundeep: Have you done the usual quick steps? Cleared the data of the app, restarted the phone, etc.? Have you considered a factory reset? That said, I think Reigo is probably right that it's a hardware problem. That it happened right after you installed an app is probably coincidental.

Comment: @Al Everett: If you say that it is a hardware problem... I am confused whether it would get set or not... Can some one plz elaborate the problem at which part it is ocured.

Comment: I don't know what the heck you're trying to say. If it's a hardware problem, you need to get the store you bought it from to replace it; we're not going to be able to help you.